# How to connect two different computer to the same account API (IBGateway/TWS)?

Tags: api, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, interactive-brokers

I am currently developing trading strategies and need to be able to work from two computers connected to the same account API. I am using the TWS API or the IBGateway API. I have tried many configuration options but still can't connect to my account API from another computer.

What I have done so far is putting the IP address of the main computer (where the desktop app is running) into the connection method of the secondary computer like this:

```
self.ib.connect(host="main computer IP", port=4001, clientId=1)
```

I also checked that the port in the line above matches the port in the TWS/IBGateway app. I tried to put the IP address of the secondary computer in the trusted IPs in the configuration of the TWS and tried the same in the IBGateway.

In addition to the steps I mentioned earlier, I also tried changing the firewall settings so that my firewall would accept the IP address of the secondary computer, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

One thing that I noticed is that if I don't check this line:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvgvV.png)

the TWS allows me to connect from my local host only after I confirm the connection in a pop-up window. However, the IBGateway won't let me connect at all.

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score -1):

i found the way. the two computers need to be connected to the same wifi. and then the IP address of the secondary computer should be added to the trusted IP in the API settings in the TWS. hope someone will find this use full. even though the problem is quite simple, i spent quite a lot of time on solving it.